# Does 'git branch -u (or --set-upstream-to)' lose tracking information of all the existing remote tracking branches?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-track

I was in my 'master' branch when I thought of creating a new branch and did it by:

```
$ git checkout -b od_newstructure
Switched to a new branch 'od_newstructure'
```

The I committed few changes and added this new branch to remote and started tracking

```
$ git commit
$ git branch -u origin/od_newstructure
Branch od_newstructure set up to track remote branch od_newstructure from origin.
$ .. some other work including git pull and git push
```

I now wanted to switch back to master. So I did

```
git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

But then, master seemed not be tracking origin/master anymore!

```
$ git branch -vv
* master          d1db2e3 Subdivided into several namespaces
  od_newstructure d1db2e3 [origin/od_newstructure] Subdivided into several namespaces
```

It was also verified by a git pull

```
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details
```

My question is why did the previous tracking branches lost its tracking information when I switched to a new tracking branch? Is this a default and sound behavior? Would I have to add upstream by `git branch -u` every time I switch to a tracking branch?

Comment: Which version of Git are you using?

Comment: Can you try with a more recent Git, to see if the issue persists?

Comment: I'm having the same issue git version 2.6.3 on MacOS